# Store app using VS 2013 Ultimate: Intellitrace calls won't work

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, store, intellitrace

I'm working on a Windows Store App and trying to use Intellitrace to trace method call states (VS 2013 Ultimate).  If I enable Intellitrace and select collection of events only, everything seems to work just fine.  But if I switch to tracing events AND CALLS, at hitting a breakpoint there is no Intellitrace window, nor any option to open it - it's as if I had not enabled Intellitrace at all.  We tested with a colleague's VS 2013 and that worked fine, so I suspect there is something wrong with my environment, but Google is not being my friend in this case.  Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the IntelliTrace team for Visual Studio. I'm sorry for your frustration. I want to assure you that there is nothing wrong with your environment. Calls information isn't supported for Windows Store Apps at this time. During the VS 2013 time frame, we found that calls information could not be correctly recorded for Windows Store Apps. In order to avoid confusion, We no longer show the IntelliTrace window when collecting calls information. The window should still show up when you are recording Events data only. Thanks for using IntelliTrace. I hope that this information helps.

Del